# Single java switch statement returns 2 variables

Tags: java, switch-statement

I am trying to setup a question and answer dialog that will ask several questions and store just as many answers. As I pass an int through `QuestionsAnswer.java`, it will set `@string/questions[i]` and `@string/answers[i]`. I have tried to find my answer through searching here and java's docs with no luck.

Pseudo code:

```
public class QuestionAnswer {

    public static void QuestionAnswer(int QuestionNum) {

        String question;
        String answer;
        switch (QuestionNum) {
            case 1:  question = "What are you doing?", answer = "activity";
                break;
            case 2:  question = "Where have you been?", answer = "Location";
                break;
            case 3:  question = "Are you looking at me?", answer = "Boolean";
                break;
            case 4:  question = "What do you think about when I'm not around?", answer = "Crazy";
                break;
            case 5:  question = "Do you want to play a game?", answer = "MovieQuote";
                break;
            case 6:  question = "Does a cat have nine lives?", answer = "CanCatsFly";
                break;
        }
          //question is a string variable that will change the question text for the dialog
        R.string.Questions = question;
          //answer is a string variable that will change what column name the answer will be stored into
        R.string.answers = answer;
    }
}
```

> Here is the finished version after the edit. It works perfectly!
>           public class QuestionAnswer {

```
    public static void QuestionAnswer(int QuestionNum) {


        String question;
        String answer;
        switch (QuestionNum) {
            case 1:  question = "What are you doing?";
                answer = "activity";
                break;
            case 2:  question = "Where have you been?";
                answer = "Location";
                break;
            case 3:  question = "Are you looking at me?";
                answer = "Boolean";
                break;
            case 4:  question = "What do you think about when I'm not around?";
                answer = "Crazy";
                break;
            case 5:  question = "Do you want to play a game?";
                answer = "MovieQuote";
                break;
            case 6:  question = "Does a cat have nine lives?";
                answer = "CanCatsFly";
                break;
        }
          //question is a string variable that will change the question text for the dialog
        R.string.Questions = question;
          //answer is a string variable that will change what column name the answer will be stored into
        R.string.answers = answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your pseudo code should work, just replace the comma (`,`) with a smicolon (`;`)...

Comment: Throw it all away and use a table of some kind.

Comment: I hate syntax errors lol... But it works great now! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `;`

```
switch (QuestionNum) {
   case 1:  question = "What are you doing?";
            answer = "activity";
            break;
            //continue with next cases
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! I have all of about 3 week in java.

Comment: @MichaelViox Welcome. I suggest you to get along with basic syntax of Java, and then read OOPS. The problem you are trying to solve has many better ways of implementation.